# Proving that $x \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Given that $g: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, if $a < b \Rightarrow g(a) < g(b)$.

I want to show that for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, we have  $x \leq g(x)$.

I use proof by induction.

Base case: Let $x=1$, then $1 \leq g(1)$.

Assume $x=k$ by Mathematical Induction: $k \leq g(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

We want to show that $x=k+1$, i.e., $k+1 \leq g(k+1)$.

I start from $$k \leq g(k)$$ Adding $1$ both sides gives, $$k+1 \leq g(k) + 1$$ 
Since $g(k) < g(k+1)$, then $$k+1 < g(k+1) + 1.$$ So $$k<g(k+1).$$
Since $k<k+1$, $k+1\leq g(k+1)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Does this proof make sense?

Note there is also a possibility that the statement can be wrong, but I think it's correct since $g$ is a monotonically increasing function. Had a hard time finding a counterexample, but that doesn't mean the statement is true.

Comment: How did you prove the base case?

Comment: @Yes, I'm not sure about the base case. Follows the assumption? Should have an inequality instead so made an edit.

Comment: The base case comes from the fact all natural numbers are at least one (the range of $g$).

Comment: @SeanNemetz That makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

You  have proved $ k<g(k+1)$ and since g(k+1) is an integer which is bigger than $k$ it must be greater or equal to $k+1$ that is $k+1\le g(k+1)$